# how to show a pop-up message(like this site) on submit form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i use of php and jquery in my application

i want when users submit success a form in page1 , forward form page1 to page2 and show a pop-up message(like this site) "success" and when they do not submit success , dont forward and just show pop-up message "error"

how i can implement this process?

thanks?

Comment: You will probably need ajax for it. Ajax + PHP

Answer (score 0):

You would use something like this:

```
<?
if($form_success) { //
   header("location: formpage2.php?success=1");
}
else {
   header("location: formpage1.php?error=1");
}
?>
```

If you wanted to pass form data from page1 to page2 on success, use either or URL query string or store whatever's in $_POST in $_SESSION.

For the popup message, I would check for a success value in the query string of formpage2 and from there use javascripts `alert` to alert the user of their success.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you can add some javascript into your form tag like so...

```
<form action="page2.php" onsubmit="if (CONDITION) {alert('Success'); return true;} else { alert('Error'); return false;}">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You can just a call a function ("return checkCondition();") in the onsubmit part and write the function in a separate Javascript file.

If the Javascript in the onsubmit part returns true, then it will go to the page specified in the action.  If it returns false, then the form validation fails and it will stay where it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on Javascript itself in the first "return CheckCondition() in onsubmit" (by Muddybruin), but I would use it! I would not rely on it because the visitor CAN turn of Javascript and easily bypass the functionality.

I would also use the "header-redirection-answer" (by Levi Hackwith), but I would modify it to:

```
<?php
//checkform.php
if($form_success) { 

//Include template or code here when form is successful

}
else {

//Include template or code here when form is unsuccessful

}
?>
```

If you absoutely must go to a specific file when form is successful, then I would include it instead of redirecting it. This is because redirections can cause unnessary issues regarding to links indexing in searchengines and it would be a lot slower than to just include directly into the checkform.php. Also keep in mind that header redirects must be sent BEFORE any other output is sent from the script.